# What is the correct structure of an async TCP server in Go?

Tags: performance, go, tcp, asyncsocket, tcpserver

I have a client sending around 500k requests (messages)/min. Each message will be around 200 bytes to 2KB. Each message will be saved in a database (like Couchbase).

What is the correct way to structure a Go TCP server in terms of cores, ports, connections and goroutines to handle this load?

Comment: What have you tried? That's not a lot of requests, so create a proof of concept and test it.

Answer (score 1):

Like JimB mentions, a TCP server shouldn't be difficult to stand up and start benchmarking for your needs. A simple layout would be to wait on incoming TCP connections and then execute a go routine to handle it. In that goroutine you can put whatever blocking code you want, in this case a write out to a DB. Here is a link to a simple example:

[Simple example](https://coderwall.com/p/wohavg/creating-a-simple-tcp-server-in-go)

Once you get that working, you can make it more sophisticated if it doesn't meet your performance standards. Here is a nice example of using a worker pool to handle 1M HTTP requests per minute.

[More sophisticated example](http://marcio.io/2015/07/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang/)

Comment: And how can I generate X TCP requests/min?